# What are the implicit assumptions that make it okay to model a satellite fly-by of the Earth as a 1D elastic collision?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, collision, celestial-mechanics

In a satellite fly-by of the Earth, a satellite approaches the Earth on a hyperbolic orbit.

In learning about collision theory in Newtonian Mechanics, I have seen results related to elastic collisions between two objects in 1D. One problem involves calculating the velocity of the satellite after it has approached Earth, gone around Earth and is leaving on the hyperbolic orbit away from the Earth.

[image]

I am trying to understand why we can treat this as a collision. Usually, in textbooks we think of two masses on a frictionless surface, they collide, and we analyze momentum, energy, and velocities before and after the collision. There is no external force except the forces during the collision interaction.

In the fly-by, there is gravitational force acting the entire time, but it doesn't seem to be important to include it in the analysis. My interpretation of this is that if you model the fly-by as a 1D problem, and you consider the satellite at an initial distance from Earth, because gravitational force is conservative, you know that when the satellite returns to the same spot but velocity in the opposite direction, the work done by the force will have been zero, so you can use that change in momentum equals zero between those two points.

**What exactly are the implicit assumptions that make it okay to model this fly-by as a 1D collision?**

**Here are my calculations for this problem**

The textbook result for 1D elastic collisions is that if we assume the velocities occur in one dimension, and that there are no forces except the interaction forces during the collision, then we can use conservation of momentum and $\Delta K=0$ to reach the conclusion that $$\vec{v}_{s,e,i}^{rel}=-\vec{v}_{s,e,f}^{rel}$$

Where the notation $\vec{v}_{s,e,i}^{rel}$ means the relative velocity of s relative to e, initially (ie before collision), and $\vec{v}_{s,e,f}^{rel}$ means the relative velocity of s relative to e, after the collision.

If we apply this result to the fly-by, using the vectors in the diagram above

$$v_i-v_{e,i}=-(v_f-v_{e,f})$$
$$\implies v_f=v_i-(v_{e,f}+v_{e,i})$$

But we also have a momentum conservation equation

$$m_sv_i+m_e v_{e,i}=-m_s v_f +m_e v_{e,f}$$

So, two equations and two unknowns $v_f$ and $v_{e,f}$.

Solution is

$$v_f=\frac{(m_e-m_s)v_i-2m_e v_{e,i}}{m_e+m_s}$$

$$v_{e,f}=\frac{(m_e-m_s)v_{e,i}+2m_s v_i}{m_e+m_s}$$

Note that if we assume that $m_s << m_e$, then we have

$$\lim_{m_s \to 0} v_f = v_i-2v_{e,i}$$ and $$\lim_{m_s \to 0} v_{e,f}=v_{e,i}$$

Answer (score 1):

> Usually, in textbooks we think of two masses on a frictionless surface, they collide, and we analyze momentum, energy, and velocities before and after the collision. There is no external force except the forces during the collision interaction.

In physics, collision happens when the momentum of a body is changed due to other body,this does not mean that they need to be in contact.
Example: Suppose two magnets are place with their north side towards each other but far enough,now if you make one magnet move towards other then the moving magnet will repel the stationary magnet and make it move but they will never come in contact.

> What exactly are the implicit assumptions that make it okay to model this fly-by as a 1D collision?

Actually there are no assumptions it is a perfectly elastic collision as you said $$v_i - v_{e,i} = -(v_f - v_{e,f})$$
Thus **coefficient of restitution** is 1.
And here I see that you are only calculating the velocity along X-axis and that's why you are considering this as a 1-D collision ( though it is a 2-D collision).
Here during the satellite orbits the earth it goes around it so we can see that the velocity along the X-axis first decreases when in the first direction and after it is at the position when it is on the X-axis (as you have taken the dotted line in your diagram) the tangential velocity of the satellite will be all along the Y-axis and zero along the X-axis and after that it starts to increase in opposite direction.
So using this explanation you can assume that the body was just moving in 1-D and it collided with a spring fixed in a wall first when the spring compresses the velocity decreases and a max. compression it's Z-axis velocity becomes zero and after that when the spring regains it original shape the velocity of the body increases in opposite direction.
Then at a greater extent you could think of a elastic body in place of a spring then the force will change to impulse and the time of the application of force will also be small.
Also it will be the same in Y-axis as you said:

> In a satellite fly-by of the Earth, a satellite approaches the Earth on a hyperbolic orbit.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: If you need more explanation then let me know I wil elaborate my answer.